# Get Git branch size

Tags: git

I'm trying to track the size of a project I'm working on. Is there an easy way to get the repository size on disk for different branches?

I tried

```
git count-objects -v
```

But it gives the same repository size for each branch.

Comment: Someplace else someone suggested to create a "bundle" with just the things you need and look at its size. That might be a good approximation of what you're looking for: `git bundle create <tmp-file> <branch> && du -sh <tmp-file>`. It does account for packing and compression, but not for on-disk size of repository you'd require to use the history (references, index file, configurations, etc).

Answer (score 18):

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6fe12b5215f4ca597accc97ac5dce0f88e8483e9/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> command learned `--disk-usage` option.

It has a [lot of examples](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1db097e107749cf6f1c2dc878c615ca2d3fb314), but regarding branch size, the command now is:

```
git rev-list --disk-usage=human --objects HEAD..<branch_name>
```

For all branches:

```bash
/* Report the disk size of each branch, not including objects used by the
  current branch. This can find outliers that are contributing to a
  bloated repository size (e.g., because somebody accidentally committed
  large build artifacts).
*/

git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' |
while read branch
do
    size=$(git rev-list --disk-usage --objects HEAD..$branch)
    echo "$size $branch"
done |
sort -n
```

See [commit a1db097](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1db097e107749cf6f1c2dc878c615ca2d3fb314), [commit 669b458](https://github.com/git/git/commit/669b4587555597da7f2a875b95dc50f503b8187f) (17 Feb 2021), and [commit 16950f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16950f8384afa5106b1ce57da07a964c2aaef3f7), [commit 3803a3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3803a3a0993045605d7f3db363188ce377e917c8) (09 Feb 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6fe12b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fe12b5215f4ca597accc97ac5dce0f88e8483e9), 25 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16950f8384afa5106b1ce57da07a964c2aaef3f7): add --disk-usage option for calculating disk usage
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> It can sometimes be useful to see which refs are contributing to the overall repository size (e.g., does some branch have a bunch of objects not found elsewhere in history, which indicates that deleting it would shrink the size of a clone).
>
> You can find that out by generating a list of objects, getting their sizes from cat-file, and then summing them, like:
>
> ```
> git rev-list --objects --no-object-names main..branch
> git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectsize:disk)' |
> perl -lne '$total += $_; END { print $total }'
> ```
>
> Though note that the caveats from git-cat-file(1) apply here.
> We "blame" base objects more than their deltas, even though the relationship could easily be flipped.
> Still, it can be a useful rough measure.
>
> But one problem is that it's slow to run.
> Teaching rev-list to sum up the sizes can be much faster for two reasons:
>
> 1. It skips all of the piping of object names and sizes.
> 2. If bitmaps are in use, for objects that are in the bitmapped packfile we can skip the `oid_object_info()` lookup entirely, and just ask the revindex for the on-disk size.
>
> This patch implements a `--disk-usage` option which produces the same answer in a fraction of the time.
> Here are some timings using a clone of torvalds/linux:
>
> ```
> [rev-list piped to cat-file, no bitmaps]
> $ time git rev-list --objects --no-object-names --all |
>   git cat-file --buffer --batch-check='%(objectsize:disk)' |
>   perl -lne '$total += $_; END { print $total }'
> 1459938510
> real  0m29.635s
> user  0m38.003s
> sys   0m1.093s
>
> [internal, no bitmaps]
> $ time git rev-list --disk-usage --objects --all
> 1459938510
> real  0m31.262s
> user  0m30.885s
> sys   0m0.376s
> ```
>
> Even though the wall-clock time is slightly worse due to parallelism, notice the CPU savings between the two.
> We saved 21% of the CPU just by avoiding the pipes.
>
> But the real win is with bitmaps.
> If we use them without the new option:
>
> ```
> [rev-list piped to cat-file, bitmaps]
> $ time git rev-list --objects --no-object-names --all --use-bitmap-index |
>   git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectsize:disk)' |
>   perl -lne '$total += $_; END { print $total }'
> 1459938510
> real  0m6.244s
> user  0m8.452s
> sys   0m0.311s
> ```
>
> then we're faster to generate the list of objects, but we still spend a lot of time piping and looking things up.
> But if we do both together:
>
> ```
> [internal, bitmaps]
> $ time git rev-list --disk-usage --objects --all --use-bitmap-index
> 1459938510
> real  0m0.219s
> user  0m0.169s
> sys   0m0.049s
> ```
>
> then we get the same answer much faster.
>
> For "--all", that answer will correspond closely to "du objects/pack", of course.
> But we're actually checking reachability here, so we're still fast when we ask for more interesting things:
>
> ```
> $ time git rev-list --disk-usage --use-bitmap-index v5.0..v5.10
> 374798628
> real  0m0.429s
> user  0m0.356s
> sys   0m0.072s
> ```

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16950f8384afa5106b1ce57da07a964c2aaef3f7/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L230-L238):

> ### `--disk-usage`
>
> Suppress normal output; instead, print the sum of the bytes used
> for on-disk storage by the selected commits or objects. This is
> equivalent to piping the output into `git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectsize:disk)'`, except that it runs much
> faster (especially with `--use-bitmap-index`). See the `CAVEATS`
> section in [`git cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file) for the limitations of what
> "on-disk storage" means.

---

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), "[`git rev-list --disk-usage`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fddd8b4801b51234b2dd525c35d74e2a578638fd/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L244)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---disk-usage))</sup> learned to take an optional value `human` to show the reported value in human-readable format, like "`3.40MiB`".

See [commit 9096451](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9096451acdf065c3dbcf609dcefe51cd68aa5d1e) (11 Aug 2022) by [Li Linchao (`Cactusinhand`)](https://github.com/Cactusinhand).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fddd8b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fddd8b4801b51234b2dd525c35d74e2a578638fd), 18 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9096451acdf065c3dbcf609dcefe51cd68aa5d1e): support human-readable output for `--disk-usage`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Li Linchao</sup>

> The '`--disk-usage`' option for [`git-rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9096451acdf065c3dbcf609dcefe51cd68aa5d1e/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> was introduced in [16950f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16950f8384afa5106b1ce57da07a964c2aaef3f7) ("`rev-list`: [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16950f8384afa5106b1ce57da07a964c2aaef3f7/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> `--disk-usage` option for calculating disk usage", 2021-02-09, Git v2.31.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fe12b5215f4ca597accc97ac5dce0f88e8483e9)).
>
> This is very useful for people inspect their git repository objects usage information, but the resulting number is quit hard for a human to read.
>
> Teach `git rev-list` to output a human readable result when using '--disk-usage=human'.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9096451acdf065c3dbcf609dcefe51cd68aa5d1e/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L253-L254):

> With the optional value `human`, on-disk storage size is shown
> in human-readable string (e.g. `12.24 Kib`, `3.50 Mib`).

---

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git for-each-ref --sort=contents:size`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a4e7440fb4b20822e1854925c0dcfae0c64402d/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L46)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---sortltkeygt))</sup>" sorts the refs according to size numerically, giving a ref that points at a blob twelve-byte (12) long before showing a blob hundred-byte (100) long.

See [commit 6d79cd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d79cd8474b7bb4979f2a7544fd736bed190261a) (02 Sep 2023) by [Kousik Sanagavarapu (`five-sh`)](https://github.com/five-sh).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6a4e744](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a4e7440fb4b20822e1854925c0dcfae0c64402d), 14 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d79cd8474b7bb4979f2a7544fd736bed190261a): sort numerically when "`:size`" is used
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kousik Sanagavarapu</sup>

> Atoms like "`raw`" and "`contents`" have a "`:size`" option which can be used to know the size of the data.
> Since these atoms have the `cmp_type` `FIELD_STR,` they are sorted alphabetically from 'a' to 'z' and '0' to '9'.
> Meaning, even when the ":size" option is used and what we ultimatlely have is numbers, we still sort alphabetically.
>
> For example, consider the the following case in a repo
>
> ```
> refname            contents:size  raw:size
> =======            =============  ========
> refs/heads/branch1 1130           1210
> refs/heads/master  300            410
> refs/tags/v1.0     140            260
> ```
>
> Sorting with "`--format="%(refname) %(contents:size) --sort=contents:size`" would give
>
> ```
> refs/heads/branch1 1130
> refs/tags/v1.0.0   140
> refs/heads/master  300
> ```

which is an alphabetic sort, while what one might really expect is:

> ```
> refs/tags/v1.0.0   140
> refs/heads/master  300
> refs/heads/branch1 1130
> ```
>
> which is a numeric sort (that is, a "`$ sort -n file`" as opposed to a "`$ sort file`", where "`file`" contains only the "`contents:size`" or "`raw:size`" info, each of which is on a newline).
>
> Same is the case with "`--sort=raw:size`".
>
> So, sort numerically whenever the sort is done with "contents:size" or "raw:size" and do it the normal alphabetic way when "contents" or "raw" are used with some other option (they are `FIELD_STR` anyways).

Answer (score 12):

Here's something really ugly:

```
$ git rev-list HEAD |                     # list commits
  xargs -n1 git ls-tree -rl |             # expand their trees
  sed -e 's/[^ ]* [^ ]* \(.*\)\t.*/\1/' | # keep only sha-1 and size
  sort -u |                               # eliminate duplicates
  awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }'   # add up the sizes in bytes
```

This will only count the blobs (not commits, trees, other), and will not account for either packing or cross-branch object sharing.  But it could serve as the basis for something useful.

Paste-able version:

```
git rev-list HEAD | xargs -n1 git ls-tree -rl | sed -e 's/[^ ]* [^ ]* \(.*\)\t.*/\1/' | sort -u | awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }'
```

Comment: Use `git rev-list --objects master |git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectsize) %(objecttype) %(objectname) %(rest)'` to get sizes of all objects which are used to make the history of a branch (or any definition of history graph, actually). It still does not account for delta-packing or compression but gives precise information of how much space you'll need to store all unique data of a repository.

Comment: Is it in bytes?

Comment: @mr5 The comment says: `# add up the sizes in bytes`.  So yes, I think it is :D

Comment: This was too slow for my repo. I sped it up:

`git rev-list HEAD |
nl |
xargs -n 2 -P 8 sh -c 'git ls-tree -rl "$1" | perl -p -e "\$_ =~ s/[^ ]*+ [^ ]*+ ([^ ]*+) ++([^\t]*+)\t.*+/\1 \2/" | sort > logfile-$0' ;
sort -m -u logfile-* | awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }' `

Answer (score 6):

This question doesn't really make sense -- in git, branches are not stored separately. Instead, there is a web of commits, and basically just the diffs are stored. The branches are just pointers to specific commits in this web of commits. So in general branches share a lot of the same information.

If you want to know the size in disk-space of a single branch, meaning, the minimal amount of disk space someone will need if they clone the repo taking only that branch, the simplest thing is probably to make a repo just like that, and then ask for the size of that repo.

Comment: I agree with what you want to say. And I know how git works. All I want to do is get increase in usage of disk size over time.

Comment: Hmm I think I see. Maybe you can try something like, clone the repo, then delete a branch, then run `git gc --aggressive` to clean up the dangling nodes, then check the disk usage?

Comment: Good answer. One thing, though; you write: *[...] basically just the diffs are stored*. Unless you're referring to packs, this statement is incorrect.

Comment: @Jubobs I see where you're going, but that is theoretical. Since the question is about the actual on disk storage, it is correct to refer to the pack implementation.

Answer (score 1):

1. clone your repository.
2. check out your specialized branch.
3. project directory size - .git file size of the repo = size of the branch.
   hint: .git involves index\ref\tags\objects of the repo.