# How to get the project specified branch file size through the gitlab API？

Tags: gitlab

How to get the project specified branch file size through the gitlab API？
or No need to download code to get branch size

Comment: Was there something that gave you the idea that this functionality exists?
GitLab has no way to give you size per branch. The only way to do that is to clone the repository and run a size checking tool
Take a look at this answer on how to do it locally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66393128/4131590

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: URL url = new URL("http://xxx/api/v4/projects/860/repository/archive.zip?private_token=8kggyQgLeUGH9qDrgkG7&sha=main");
 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  int fileLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();
  System.out.println(fileLength);